# How do you limit the number of input arguments for python's input() function?

Tags: python, list, input, python-3.8

Let's say I have this:

```
maxNumOfArgs = int(input("enter length of list: "))

listOfNums = input("enter space separated list elements: ")
```

Nothing is stopping the user from entering more arguments than `maxNumOfArgs`. Is there a concise, pythonic way to limit the number of entered arguments in the `input()` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you split the second input string, you can then strip off any arguments beyond the requested maximum length

```
# Get requested length
max_num_args = int(input("enter length of list: "))

# Get input string of comma-separated elements
all_inputs = input("enter space separated list elements: ")

# Split string by comma and only keep up to the maximum requested list length
input_values = all_inputs.split(',')[:max_num_args]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you split the `str` returned by `input()`, you can limit the number of splits by passing a parameter `maxsplit`.

Example:

```
>>> test = input("enter data: ")
a b c d e f
>>> args = test.split(" ", maxsplit=3)
>>> args
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd e f']
```

Note that, in the worst case, the array returned by split will have 4 elements, since you limited it to 3 splits.